# How can i change the ascii value for my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I spilled some water on my keyboard and some keys are not working: [ W, H, P, K, >, backspace ]

How can i change the ascii value to use other less important keys? I'm currently using an on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Better to fix/replace in this case. Your typing will suffer. Unless you don't use English much. Plus, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: @jiggunjer: In that case please *flag → should be closed… → duplicate of…*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Windows, you can use SharpKeys to remap any key to any other key, including disabling keys that would otherwise type by mistake. Do note that it's possible hardware still limits how many keys are simultaneously pressed so you may have trouble with keys such as Ctrl-C after the remapping. Do note that the remap takes place on reboot.

On Linux, you may use xmodmap. You would remap scancodes. Unlike on Windows I have no special GUI program (on Windows SharpKeys really changes a registry setting).

Comment: thank you .. would it change ctrl even if i didn't change it ?

Comment: can i use it on win 10?

Comment: It only changes keys you explicitly request. It works on all versions of Windows NT (thus 10 too)